# How can I view the implicitly_wait that the webdriver was set with?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have automation scripts where the implicitly_wait is parametrized so that the user will be able to set it. I have a default value of 20 seconds which I am aware of but there is a chance that the user has set it with a different value.

In one of my methods I would like to change the implicitly_wait (to lower it as much as possible) and return it to the value before the method was called. In order to do so I would like to save the implicitly_wait value before I change it. This is why I am looking for a way to reach to it.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Would you like to look at a line of code which will fetch you the _implicitly_wait value_ any time from your script whenever invoked?

Comment: Thanks. It would be great.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the Selenium code and playing in the interpreter, it appears there is no way to retrieve the current implicit_wait value. This is a great opportunity to add a wrapper to your framework. The wrapper should be used any time a user wants to change the implicit wait value. The wrapper would store the current value and provide a 'getter' to retrieve the current value. Otherwise, you can submit a request to the Selenium development team...

Comment: Thanks. I also was playing around with the interpreter but I thought that I am not into all the bits and bytes in order to find what i was looking for. I will search for another solution (without changing the implicitly_wait) if there is no simple one